# RecyclerViewで、アダプタからではなくアクティビティからonClickの処理を行う

Tags: android, java

情報のリストを表示する際にRecyclerViewを使いました。
リスト表示の後、消去ボタンを押すと外部ストレージのデータを消去し、リストのデータを更新して表示するようにしたいのですが、
このときMainActivityで消去ボタンの処理を行なわなければいけません。
どのように行えば良いのでしょうか？

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Activity thisActivity = this;

    List<HashMap<String, String>> worldDatas = new ArrayList<>();

    String sdPath = getExternalStoragePath();
    final String WORLD_NAME_KEY = "name";
    final String WORLD_PATH_KEY = "path";
    final String WORLD_SIZE_KEY = "size";

    RecyclerView worldInfoContainer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        updateWorldsList();
    }

//端末のフォルダからリストのデータを更新
    private void updateWorldsList() {
        worldInfoContainer = (RecyclerView) findViewById (R.id.worldInfoContainer);
        worldDatas = new ArrayList<>();
        //...

        worldInfoContainer.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(thisActivity));
        worldInfoContainer.setHasFixedSize(true);

        worldInfoContainer.setAdapter(new WorldDataAdapter(thisActivity, worldDatas));
    }
//ディレクトリを消去
    public void deleteDirectory(File file) {
        //...
    }

    public static String getExternalStoragePath() {
        //...
    }
}
```

WorldDataAdapter.java

```
public class WorldDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WorldDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    List<HashMap<String, String>> worldDatas = new ArrayList<>();

    final String WORLD_NAME_KEY = "name";
    final String WORLD_PATH_KEY = "path";
    final String WORLD_SIZE_KEY = "size";

    public WorldDataAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> dataList) {
        super();
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        worldDatas = dataList;
    }

    @Override
    public WorldDataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.template_world_info, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return worldDatas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final HashMap<String, String> positionData = worldDatas.get(position);

        holder.worldNameText.setText(positionData.get(WORLD_NAME_KEY));
        holder.worldPathText.setText(positionData.get(WORLD_PATH_KEY));
        holder.worldSizeText.setText(positionData.get(WORLD_SIZE_KEY));

        holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //MainActivityで実行したい
            }
        });
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView worldNameText;
        TextView worldPathText;
        TextView worldSizeText;

        ImageButton deleteButton;
        public ViewHolder(final View v) {
            super(v);

            worldNameText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.worldNameText);
            worldPathText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.worldPathText);
            worldSizeText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.worldSizeText);

            deleteButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

クラスの定義をMainActivityに入れたところ、動作しました。